# Using certain elements of an image in the [ImageView] widget as buttons

Tags: android, button, imageview

So lets say I have a segmented circle image asset inside an 'ImageView' widget, and I want to use each segment of that circle as a clickable surface to bring up a fragment with an image and some info.

Is there any way to build transparent arrangeable borders that I  can use to do this with?

I'm using android studio with the default NavigationDrawer activity if that helps.

Comment: Be a bit more specific please, how do you segment that circle exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding some ImageViews with transparent images on top of each section and making them clickable? That's how I'd do it. Of course this won't cover perfectly the area but it may work for what you need it.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this. In case it can be of help to anyone else:

https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu